Mileage reimbursement advice
I'm an administrative assistant at a small law firm and part of my job involves running errands for the office, such as picking up supplies or filing documents at the courthouse. This often requires using my personal vehicle and accumulating mileage. While I understand that these tasks are part of my role, there's never been any discussion about mileage reimbursement.
With the recent rise in gas prices, the cost of these errands has become increasingly noticeable, and I'm starting to feel a bit concerned about the financial impact.
Is it appropriate to approach my boss about mileage reimbursement? What are the typical mileage reimbursement rates, and are there any standard forms or templates I could use?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Upd.: I'm located in Hillside, IL.

Please specify your country. typical rates vary by location. There can also be tax issues.

Before you do anything make sure you have worked out for yourself how much money is involved and that is enough to be worth bothering with.

On a slightly different note, in the UK your private / personal car insurance might not actually cover you if you’re running errands for work as you may need business cover as well. Claiming work mileage might make it hard to claim you only use it for personal trips. Not sure how that works in other jurisdictions, so have a read of the small print. (Source:  https://www.gocompare.com/car-insurance/insuring-your-car-for-work-use/# “Many drivers remain unaware that they must specify business use on their car insurance if they drive their car for any work purpose beyond their daily commute.”

The amount of reimbursement allowed by the IRS for business travel. per mile is $0.67 in 2024

On a side-note, ask for mileage reimbursement initially via email. Even if they say no, having a time-stamped record of your request would be useful if shit hits the fan or if you get into a serious car accident while performing these work tasks.

A law firm ought to know better. The liability is crazy. Your not in CA, but IL is almost as a bad for employer's liability when an employee is driving a vehicle. The insurance question should be documented. If you're in a wreck, you'll be sued. Who will fix your vehicle? Hopefully you'll never need to use these insurances. Better safe than sorry.

@DogBoy37 It does not surprise me. My personal experience with law firms is they gas light a lot their employees.

@TomSawyer off topic, a long time ago I was expert witness in a case for a law firm suing a computer company. The opposing consul asked "You are testifing today because you want XYZ as a client". I said "Hell no, lawyers are the worst customers". The judge laughed. The look on the opposing consul's face was priceless.


Is it appropriate to approach my boss about mileage reimbursement?

Absolutely!

What are the typical mileage reimbursement rates, and are there any standard forms or templates I could use?

The IRS announces mileage reimbursement rates each year. For 2024, it's $0.67/mile.

I wouldn't stress too much about asking your boss about mileage reimbursement. If they freak out, well, that might tell you something about the company anyway...
Look up the standard mileage rates, the IRS usually has them listed. That way you have a ballpark figure in mind. There are several free mileage reimbursement forms you can fill out (Lawrina worked well for me). It'll make you look organized and make things easier for your boss too.
Another idea: maybe they have a company car you could use for errands? Might be worth asking, it would solve the whole gas problem and save wear and tear on your own car.
Good luck!
